# NodeJS: Express 3.0 with connect-flash( as advised in the passport local strategy), still finding exception for req.flash

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm new to NodeJS and trying to build an app over Express3.0, included passport local strategy for authentication purpose. But the following exception(with respect to req.flash) blocks my progress.

```
Exception occurs in the following line.
res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('error') });
```

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object # has no method 'flash'

    at /Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/app.js:115:54
    at callbacks (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:162:37)
    at param (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:136:11)
    at pass (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:143:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:171:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at store.get.next (/Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:310:9)
    at /Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:333:9
    at /Users/vivekanandan/Source/Git/ExpressApp/CosmicEnergyCoupled/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:52:9
```

I have installed connect-flash to recover the deprecated req.flash method as advised by the author(passport-local-strategy). Please find the npm packages installed in the app.

```
├── connect-flash@0.1.0
├── ejs@0.8.3
├── ejs-locals@0.2.5
├─┬ express@3.0.0
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├─┬ connect@2.6.0
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ ├── qs@0.5.1
│ │ └─┬ send@0.0.4
│ │   └── mime@1.2.6
│ ├── cookie@0.0.4
│ ├── crc@0.2.0
│ ├── debug@0.7.0
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.6
├─┬ passport@0.1.12
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3
├─┬ passport-local@0.1.6
│ ├── passport@0.1.12
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3
├─┬ socket.io@0.9.10
│ ├── policyfile@0.0.4
│ ├── redis@0.7.2
│ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.10
│   ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1
│   │ └── zeparser@0.0.5
│   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5
│   ├─┬ ws@0.4.22
│   │ ├── commander@0.6.1
│   │ ├── options@0.0.3
│   │ └── tinycolor@0.0.1
│   └── xmlhttprequest@1.4.2
└─┬ stylus@0.30.1
  ├── cssom@0.2.5
  ├── debug@0.7.0
  └── mkdirp@0.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main app.configure method

```
app.use(flash());
```

Comment: yeah, i added this to my configuration. And still it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install connect-flash --save

var flash = require('connect-flash')
app.use(flash());
```

You're using it wrong I think. You just have to call req.flash() with type and message before res.redirect

```
   req.flash('info', 'Welcome to the site, a welcome email has been sent to you.');
   res.redirect('/');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, also I'm not trying anything new, i just followed the example provided by the [author jared-hanson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/620181/jared-hanson). For more details, please have a look at the line 106 in this [code snippet](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3/app.js).

Comment: Did you add app.use(flash()); above your routes in app.js?

Comment: i have already added app.use(flash()); Still don't know what went wrong, but it works after stripped down few packages and npm install.

Comment: The problem happens already to me: I perceive this module as "unstable" or not ripe because it doesn't work as expected and how it's pointed out in the official wiki.